# Using SNMP class with php on Windows

Tags: php, windows, snmp

I am trying to use the SNMP class with PHP 5.6 on a Windows 2008R2 server. I have installed net-snmp for Windows but when I try the sample program

```
<?php
$session = new SNMP(SNMP::VERSION_1, "127.0.0.1", 'public')
?>
```

I get a `PHP Fatal error: Class 'SNMP' not found` error.

On my Fedora system I had to also install a php-snmp package. Is that what I'm missing on Windows?